# How to open and compile a Delphi 5 project in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-5

Is there an IDE to open a legacy Delphi 5 project?
The Delphi XE seems doesn't support delphi 5.

Comment: Open the DPR file just like always. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Did you make sure that all components used by the project are installed in XE?

Comment: And you are prepared for the Ansi to Unicode switch?

Comment: The IDE for delphi 5 projects is delphi 5

Comment: If you have difficulties adapting your code to Unicode,  you can get some earlier versions with your XE license (http://embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions). Moving to D2007 or D7 may be easier as there is no change in the meaning of "string".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll open the D5 *.dpr and create an .dproj file (besides other files) to configure the default environment.
If you have reports, probably you need to acquire an QuickReport user license, the last version that came with it was Delphi 7.
And after that - the Unicode conversion (which can very difficult or very easy, depending of the codebase).

Answer (score 5):

Many things have changed between Delphi 5 and XE.

One of the biggest is Unicode Strings.

- Delphi Version 2 - 2007 : String = AnsiString
- Delphi Version 2009 - XE : String = UnicodeString

Your code will need to change to handle this.  There are many other Questions here on Stack Overflow that cover this topic.

In addition to this change upgrading from version to version requires a bit more than just open and compile.   Further clarification on the problem you are having would help refine the answers to your question.

Here are the steps I typically go through when upgrading.

**Remove all DCU, DCP and BPL files that are in your source directories.**

If you have setup well defined output directories typically all you have to do is change your output directory.

**Install/Upgrade all components in the new version of Delphi**

Heads up some components (Example QuickReport and Decision Cube) that were installed by default before, don't exist in the default installation.  Decision Cube still ships but is now in the demos directory.  QuickReport is no longer part of the product.

You also may have had 3rd Party components that need to be upgraded.

**Open Project, verify each form and datamodule will open without errors**

These errors tend to indicate that you have a component not installed and/or the interface of the component changed.  Either way if you read and follow the error messages you should be
able to work through these.

**Build Your project**

Fix any compile errors.   If you have used `$IFDEF VERXXX` in your code you may need to change this logic to be correct with the new version.

Resolve all warnings.   Compiler warnings typically point out bad code that may break.   Each version of Delphi typically introduces a few new warnings.   For example ignoring
the string warnings will most likely cause your application to behave incorrectly.

Comment: Actually the 1st part of the warning (*Heads up some components(...)* ) applies only to Decision Cube. QuickReports have to be bought since the last version that it came with the IDE was D7.

Comment: @Fabricio - Although QR exists, it's not in the default installation.  What I said applies to both.

Comment: @RobLove - QR in XE install? At least in D2010 there's no trace of QuickReport anywhere.

Comment: @RobLove - Does not. There's no QR*.* or (anything with QR in the name) files on my Drive C: (where Delphi lives). No BPLs, dcu or whatever.

Comment: @Rob - D7 brought QuickReports in the Demos folder - not installing in the IDE pallete by default. That was the last time QR was in a Delphi IDE install.

Comment: Correct QR does not exist in Delphi XE.   You have buy it and install it.   Hence why I said "Don't Exist"

Comment: Decision Cube exist in the install, but is not registered on the IDE pallete by default. QR doesn't exist AT ALL in the IDE installation. (Look at [DelphiPath]\source\Win32\xtab\MXDB.PAS for decision cube)

Comment: An better example would be Decision Cube and TClientSocket/TServerSocket components. QR is not the same case, as is not bundled with the IDE anymore.